# Rails belongs_to one of two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

I'm working with two different models `Person` and `Organization`.  Among many other attributes, both a `Person` and `Organization` can be a `Contractor`.  If I was working with just the `Person` model and wanted to store contractor information I would say that `Contractor` `belongs_to :person` and be done with it.  However this seems like `Contractor` belongs to two other models.

I searched around on google and found a lot of info about how to assign ownership to two different models at once.  (For example a `Sale` must belong to both a `Buyer` and a `Seller`.)  But in my situation a `Contractor` is EITHER a `Person` or an `Organization`.  Is there any way to elegantly store `Contractor` information for both models in the same table?

If not, I figure I can always make two different contractor tables, but I figured this might be an opportunity to learn something.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try this. Rails provide [polymorphic-associtions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). You can try to build one model named ContractorInfo belongs to Contractable(use polymorphic: true), then Person has_one ContractorInfo as contractable, Organization has_one ContractorInfo as Contractable.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ShallmentMo, but as additional, You could define something like this:

`Models`

```
class Contractor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contractable, polymorphic: true 
  ...
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contractors, as: :contractable
  ...
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :contractors, as: :contractable
  ...
end
```

`Migrations`

```
create_table :contractors , force: true do |t|
  t.references :contractable, polymorphic: true, index: true
  ...
  t.timestamps null: false    
end
```

`Usage`

```
  def create
    @contractor = Contractor.new(params[:contractor])
    contractable = params[:contractor][:contractable].split(":")
    @contractor.contractable_type = contractable[0] # String: 'Person' or 'Organization'
    @contractor.contractable_id = contractable[1].to_i # Integer: id of 'Person' or 'Organization'
    ...
```